# Manipulating DOM of an uncontrolled react component

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, react-dom

I have a react component that in essence renders a **contentEditable** div. It is uncontrolled in that react doesn't control the content of the div.

```
class UncontrolledDiv extends React.Component<{}, void>{
   public render(): JSX.Element {
      return (<div contentEditable='true'></div>);
   }
}
```

[This is a simplified version of a content-editable div that I have written]

I have functionality that clears the content of the div when a button is clicked. I want to unit test the same and so I want to manipulate the dom by actually adding content to the div and checking if it gets cleared when the button is pressed.

Any pointers as to how I can achieve this?

**PS**: I'm using enzyme as a test framework

Comment: where does the content inside the div comes from in your normal flow?

Comment: A human would enter text into the div.

Comment: Yes, how do you store it? You have it as a state or a prop?

Comment: It comes down to this component as a prop. Its a stateless component. There is a change function on the component that the parent consumes, updates its state and passes it down to this component.

Comment: adding a default text to your div would help. Just pass the props from parent to this content editable div.